# amcharts4 is not compiling with angular 6

Tags: angular, amcharts

I'm having trouble with compiling my app when including amcharts4. I have simply installed the amcharts4 npm package and am trying to use it in a component i've created. Am i missing something with the CLI config?

```
ERROR in node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/core/utils/Object.d.ts(60,117): error TS2536: Type 'Key' cannot be used to index type 'Object'.
node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/core/utils/Object.d.ts(67,109): error TS2536: Type 'Key' cannot be used to index type 'Object'.
node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/core/utils/Object.d.ts(76,116): error TS2536: Type 'Key' cannot be used to index type 'Object'.
node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/core/utils/Type.d.ts(25,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Extract'.
```

my typescript:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";
import am4themes_animated from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated";

am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);


@Component({
  selector: 'app-am-charts',
  templateUrl: './am-charts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./am-charts.component.css']
})
export class AmChartsComponent {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Per <s>[this issue](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/375)</s> [this newer closed issue](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/546) and our [angular integration documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/using-typescript-or-es6/#TypeScript_strict_mode), make sure you have the following in your tsconfig.json as AmCharts 4 does not currently support strict mode:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "strictFunctionTypes": false
    }
}
```

In addition to this, make sure you're at least on TypeScript version <s>2.7</s> 2.8 but not 3.x as it isn't supported yet.

Comment: After adding this to tsconfig.json i'm still receiving the same issue

Comment: I've tried setting up a new app up fresh using angular cli v6.1.2 and typescript is on 2.7.2 and im still getting the same issue

Comment: Try TypeScript 2.8. I forgot that we bumped our minimum TS requirement from [this other issue](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/546).

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ts-ignore` anotation which ignores errors in typescript code:

```
// @ts-ignore
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";

// @ts-ignore
import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";
```

And update typescript version for example to newest:

```
npm install typescript@next --save
```

For me it was: `"typescript": "^3.4.0-dev.20190220"`